# libclang: How to distinguish project and system includes?

Tags: c++, libclang

I am using libclang (Python bindings) to parse some C++ code.
I need to distinguish includes that resolve to system headers, e.g., `#include <algorithm>`, from includes that resolve to project-local headers, e.g., `#include "my_header.h"`.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to retrive this information from the libclang AST.

Some thoughts/considerations:

- the information has to be there somewhere, since running clang with `-E` (only run preprocessor), system includes are marked by appending the flag `3` when they are included. Example:
  `# 1 "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/exception" 1 3`
- of course, I could invoke the preprocessor myself and match the results, but this adds overhead and more potential sources for bugs
- simply look for `<>` vs `""` in the tokens of the include statement does not work, as they just determine lookup order.
- checking the beginning of the expanded include file path for sth like `/usr/lib/...` does not work, since it is not platform independent and the user can add custom "system" directories via `-isystem`.

I hope you can help me out on this :)

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between project and system includes?

Comment: Heavily simplified, I need to recursively walk project includes but not system includes

Comment: does [this](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FullSourceLoc.html#a98ffaccf4e6822a7ffced0d7f6b4aee1) help?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. From first look, I guess this would solve my problem, but this function is not exposed in the Python bindings :(

Comment: Well, add it then, and submit a patch...

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. While this would benefit in the long run, I need to support quite a trail of legacy versions, so this is not a solution to the problem

Comment: Sorry & thanks, I get what you mean now with what you wrote for the bullet point.  I deleted my comment.  Interesting challenge!